# Default Parameter Value in Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

I'm new to ES6 Javascript which means i'm exploring it. I like the arrow function and default parameter feature from ES6 which is mentioned in the below site.

http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies
http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues

Below is my code snippet of ES6 and i have tested this in `Chrome 47`. I'm trying to give default parameter value for my arrow function which is currently throwing error like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  'use strict';
  var greet = (name = 'Venkat') => (console.log('Hi ' + name + '!'));
  greet(); // expected output: Venkat
  greet('Venkatraman'); // expected output: Venkatraman
</script>
```

Let me know whether its possible, if so, explain with solution and what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Chrome 47 [doesn't support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-default_function_parameters) default parameters yet (48 does, albeit behind an experimental flag). Your code is valid ES6, so [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20greet%20%3D%20(name%20%3D%20'Venkat')%20%3D%3E%20(console.log('Hi%20'%20%2B%20name%20%2B%20'!'))%3B%0Agreet()%3B) works just fine.

Comment: provide simple babeljs setup for transpile this code

Comment: Very very very similar to this question, which has an answer that may be more helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51913154/176877

Answer (score 10):

No, that's not possible (yet, I suppose). What you *can* do though:

```
var greet = name => console.log('Hi ' + (name || 'Venkat') + '!');
greet(); // output: Venkat
greet('Venkatraman'); // output: Venkatraman
```

Try it [here](https://repl.it/B92i)

[**jan 2018**] The default parameter value is now supported in all major browsers I suppose

Comment: Thanks for your solution. what happens if i have 4 variables inside the function. this will increase more lines of code.

Comment: Yep. We'll have to live with it untill there's full support for default parameter values

Answer (score 1):

It seems it support only in Firefox

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: Yes you are right. i tested the code. its working ! my plan is to learn and implement browser compatible snippet for the above problem !

Answer (score 0):

From todays view it is indeed possible - I don't know if it was back then.

The syntax is the following:

```
const arrowfunctionidentifier = (parameter = defaultValue) => {<content of the function>}
```

I mean it is basically the same as yours but with curly braces for the function body. Maybe this is the critical difference?

Cheers

Edit: I added a little snipped, for testing purposes :)

```js
const greeting = (user = 'stranger') => {
  console.log(`Greetings! ${user}`);
};

greeting();
greeting('mwannags');
```

Comment: See the first comment on the question - yes, the problem was that it was not implemented yet in all environments in 2015.